# Firebase reset password issue

Tags: ios, firebase

Just a quick question.  I have setup a backend using Firebase and I am using swift.  I have the create a user, login a user and forgot a password all working correctly.  But does anyone know how to check when a user logs in if they are using the reset password from the email which was sent out.

What I want to do is check upon login if they are using the email reset password and if so I can then enforce a password change upon them.  I cannot seem to find out how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a user requests a forgot password email, they will receive an email with a temporary (24 hour) token that they must log-in with and then change their password from there.

Check the documentation for more information regarding password and email changes within your application. https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/password.html

Comment: I created a login on my app for myself and did the forgot password.  I then received the email with the temp password which I used to log in with in my app, it then logs in and continues as normal.  There is no request to change password.  I guess that a possible way would be to create a user database which puts in an entry when someone presses forgot password, then when they login again it will check to see if the entry is there and then force the user to change to password.  I was just hoping there was a simple line of code which could check if they logged in using the temp password instead.

Comment: Sorry Trenton, just spotted it at the bottom when looking over the page again : providerData[@"isTemporaryPassword"].  sometimes my brain it just hurts sooo much, lol

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled this was slightly differently than what you described, but it gets to the same place.  After the user gets a temporary password they are prompted to enter in the temporary password sent to their email.  Immediately after they enter it they are then asked to change their password to something new before they can proceed.  I figured those temporary passwords are so complex no one is going to remember or hold onto them for long, so it's best to get them using their own password ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth

In Swift 3.x and Firebase 3.x

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordReset(withEmail: email) { error in

    // Your code here
}
```

Firebase 4 Version

```
Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: email) { error in

    // Your code here
}
```